# How can I release my Codename One application so it will be available only to tablets

Tags: android, codenameone

I'm trying to distribute an app that was designed specifically to tablets and not handsets. To avoid negative reviews I'd like it to only appear for tablets on the appstores for iOS/Android respectively.

In the iOS section of the project preferences I noticed there is an option to pick the project type but I saw no such option for Android.

[image: iOS option to pick iPad project type]

Comment: strange... asked and answered by the same account on the same second?

Comment: By the same person. When asking a question there is an option to answer your own question. We use this when we get pro-email support questions, this allows us to share common questions with the community and answer in a more transparent way. Obviously only relevant for non-proprietary information.

Comment: ah ok, he is the co-founder of Codename One. Using SO as wiki...

Comment: Support platform, not wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen sizes are more varied and nuanced on Android than they are in iOS. Android includes the [compatible-screens option](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) and this [higher level tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html).

To apply this to Codename One just use the build hint `android.xapplication` and set the relevant XML to it e.g.:

```
android.xapplication=<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```